Chinese Chromebook character entry
https://www.reddit.com/r/Crostini/wiki/enable-chrome-shortcuts-in-linux-apps/ with the addition of <Control>space allows me to use the native ChromeOS input method to type Chinese, into all Linux programs except emacs. Yes, I undefined CTRL+Space in emacs. Currently the best I can do is just use "emacs -nw". No I don't want to use Emacs' built in Quail modes.  In xfce I can type Chinese, but emacs -Q just hears ASCII. Sounds like me:
How to input Chinese on CentOS7 using system input method?

In ~/.emacs put:
(setq x-gtk-use-native-input t)
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-SPC"))

In ~/.bash_profile put:
export GTK_IM_MODULE=cros

Now in emacs CTRL+SPACE should toggle on Chinese for you.
I read about it on
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Unibyte-Mode.html#index-GTK-input-methods

Dan, you are so brilliant. But what about us who are using slightly older emacses, where there is no x-gtk-use-native-input?
